# Is there a word for batlike?

Tags: single-word-requests

The word for snakelike is ophidian. 
The word for froglike is batrachian.
Is there a word for batlike?

Comment: This sort of thing is listed in so many places, [including here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_animal_names), that I’m going to call this one on General Reference.

Comment: @tchrist You know, I searched for an answer on Google but I didn't find anything immediately. If the purpose of SE is to improve the internet, perhaps the existence of this answer will help people more easily find an answer they can use when they search "word for batlike" or "word for relating to bats". I also tried searching for a modification (chiropteric) of the corresponding biological classifier 'chiroptera'. Someone else might experience the same difficulty finding the answer if this answer doesn't appear on Google.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, "***chiropteran***" ("*hand-wingy*"):

> *[**chiropteran**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/chiropteran): (adj) relating to or denoting bats.*

Also, @Frank says the OED uses "***cheiropteran***" (*eiro* instead of *iro*).

Answer (score 8):

You already have your answer:

[batlike](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/batlike)

This is a good choice because:

1. it is a recognized word
2. a reader will immediately understand your meaning

Comment: You're right, Lovecraft's works would be much improved if he dropped this obscure vocabulary "*Among these reliefs were fabulous monsters of abhorrent grotesqueness and malignity - half ichthyic and half batrachian in suggestion - which one could not dissociate from a certain haunting and uncomfortable sense of pseudomemory, as if they called up some image from deep cells and tissues whose retentive functions are wholly primal and awesomely ancestral.*" and simply said "*Eww, gross. Fish-frogs! They're, like, **really** old*."

Comment: @DanBron I must agree with you.  There is a certain beauty in the verbiage.  I, sadly, cannot always easily understand the message the author intends.  When I write, I prefer a simpler, more journalistic style.

Comment: @DanBron The juxtaposition of his original passage and the ineloquent reinterpretation evokes a sense of joviality within the reader. In other words: lol

Comment: @DanBron "Eww, gross. Fish-frogs! They freak me out so much it's like our species evolved to be freaked out by them," would be a more accurate translation. We evolved to be revolted by rotting food because it keeps us healthy; it's not that the fish-frogs are old *per se*, it's that they're immediately repulsive in a this-must-be-for-a-reason sort of a way. (In other words, score one more for the plain English campaign!)

Comment: @David, Ha, thanks, I know (but paraphrasing Lovecraft well wasn't my aim ;)